# How can I give the edges of my shadows a certain shape?

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

Essentially, I am looking for a way to deform the shadows on my object to match the textures.

Example:

[image: WIP]

I want the shadow's edges (and only the edges) to have the same or at least a similar structure to the texture I applied to the object, rather than just being a straight gradient. I think this would really help with making the texture and shading bleed into each other more.

Comment: if I understand correctly, maybe plug your texture into the Height socket of a Vector > Bump node and plug the Bump node into the Normal socket of your Principled BSDF (or your Diffuse if you've used a Diffuse)

Comment: doesn't achieve the desired result, unfortunately. The best way I can explain it is ... imagine the shadow wouldn't be able to cross the individual cells of the voronoi cells and could only move along the edges

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone finds this small post sometime in the future, [this video](https://youtu.be/2ZR5XIjBmho?t=708) offers somewhat of a solution. Just do what he does in this section with whatever texture you want your shadow to conform to.